# How to update a UITextField when receiving input from a UIPickerView?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uitextfield, uipickerview

Currently, I am programmatically creating a `UITextField` and `UIPickerView` within `cellForRowAt`. I can easily update the selected `UIPickerView` value within `didSelectRow` if I connect my `UITextField` to an `IBOutlet`.

However, I require the `UITextField` to be created programmatically with applied AutoLayout constraints.

However, I don't know how to update the `UITextField` as I have no reference to it in the `UIPickerView's` `didSelectRow` function since it's created programmatically within `cellForRowAt` like so:

```
var testing: [String] = []

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    // Dequeue the cell to load data
    let cell: UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)

    if indexPath.section == 2
    {
        let wearsPickerView: UIPickerView = UIPickerView()

        wearsPickerView.delegate = self
        wearsPickerView.dataSource = self

        let textField: UITextField = UITextField()

        textField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        textField.textColor = UIColor.black

        textField.text = "Test"

        textField.delegate = self
        textField.inputView = wearsPickerView

        cell.contentView.addSubview(textField)

        let leadingConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: cell.contentView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.leading, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: textField, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.leading, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
        let trailingConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: cell.contentView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.trailing, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: textField, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.trailing, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
        cell.contentView.addConstraint(leadingConstraint)
        cell.contentView.addConstraint(trailingConstraint)

        let topConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: cell.contentView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.top, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: textField, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
        let bottomConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: cell.contentView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.bottom, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: textField, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
        cell.contentView.addConstraint(topConstraint)
        cell.contentView.addConstraint(bottomConstraint)
    }

    return cell
}

func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool
{
    textField.resignFirstResponder()

    return true
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int
{
    return testing.count
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String?
{
    return testing[row]
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int)
{
    // How to update UITextField string?

}
```

Comment: is your table view static, e.g. your input text field is always in section 2, index 0? Is your cell a UITableViewCell subclass or simply a UITableViewCell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the cell for the corresponding index path, and find the textfield in that cell. You have 2 options for finding the textField. One would be to use tags, in case you had more than one `UITextField`s in that cell, which you don't. So you can do it like this:

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int)
  {
    // choose the correct row. I've assumed you only have one row.
    if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 2)) {
      for subview in cell.subviews {
        if let textField = subview as? UITextField {
          textField.text = testing[row]
          break
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: not sure why but it doesn't enter the if statement when checking if it's a `UITextField`

Comment: figured it out using tag instead but similar implementation as suggested

Comment: Even if you use tags, you eventually have to cast to a `UITextField` to access `UITextField` specific methods and properties, such as `.text`.