# set value from pickerview to textfield without declaring the textfield globally swift programatically

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uipickerview

I am building the UI textfields dynamically using the schema, I have many textfields that require UIPickerView(). I am using the UIPickerViewDelegate and overriding its method to set the selected value to the textfields.
 but the problem is I have many textfields generated dynamically at the runtime, I don't want them to be declared globally or in class scope

How can can I set the value selected in picker to the textfield without globally declaring textfield

Comment: simple assign the tag for each textfield and access via tag your concept

Comment: You don't need to declare all textfields globally. Just create one textfield globally for storing current textfield reference.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43087586/1691367

Answer (score 0):

When you generate the textfields, assign a unique `tag` to each of them. I assume you are already using a loop to do this, so getting a unique number should not be too hard:

```
for i in 0..<someNumber {
    // ...
    textField.tag = i
}
```

To get a specific text field, you just do

```
view.viewByTag(someNumber) as! UITextField
```

where `view` is the superview of the text field.